# How to rename a database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception, ssms

I am trying to rename my database in sql by using

```
SP_renameDB 'master', 'companyCode';
ALTER DATABASE master MODIFY name = companycode;
```

but I get these errors:

> Msg 15227, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_renameDB, Line 52 [Batch Start Line 148]
> The database 'master' cannot be renamed.
>
> Msg 5016, Level 16, State 1, Line 151
> Cannot change the name of the system database master.

Why is this happening? Please help

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  The question is tagged with MySQL and (MS) SQL Server.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems really, really clear.

Comment: Unfathomable what you are expecting to accomplish by trying to rename `master`, unless breaking your SQL Server installation is the goal?

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear. You simply cannot rename system databases nor should you try.